# I keep getting a "parse error" and a "can't find" error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, gameboy

I'm attempting to learn a bit of C to program games for the Game Boy from a tutorial, and I keep getting two errors: A "parse error" and a "can't find" error. Can anybody tell what's going on and how to fix it?

I've only tried running what I have, as I am extremely new to C and don't know much.

My main file:

```
#include <gb\gb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    printf("HELLO WORLD");
}
```

This .bat file I'm trying to use to get it to .gb:

```
c:\gbdk\bin\lcc -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -c -o main.o main.c
c:\gbdk\bin\lcc -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -o main.gb main.o
```

This is the result of the above code:

```
PS C:\Users\cdbil\Documents\gameboycode\helloworld> .\make.bat

C:\Users\cdbil\Documents\gameboycode\helloworld>c:\gbdk\bin\lcc -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -c -o main.o main.c

main.c(1) parse error: token -> '' ; column 0

C:\Users\cdbil\Documents\gameboycode\helloworld>c:\gbdk\bin\lcc -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -o main.gb main.o
c:\gbdk\bin\lcc: can't find `main.o'
PS C:\Users\cdbil\Documents\gameboycode\helloworld>
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't want `#include <gb/gb.h>`?  Or does it really accept `\ ` under windows?

Comment: Tom! Thank you so much haha. I know this probably seemed like a super simple thing, but I've been stuck on this for like 3 hours.